# Placing HBox in BorderPane throws Exception in start method, JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a layout consisting of a TreeView List and a couple of textfields, buttons at the bottom. I figured i'd use a BorderPane to hold my layout in place. But i am getting an `Exception in Application start method` and it also tells me `Children: duplicate children added: parent = BorderPane@71e344e8`

Do you guys have an idea of whats going on?

```
 public class Main extends Application {

        Stage window;
        TextField nameInput, quantityInput;
        TreeView<String> tree;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

            window = primaryStage;
            window.setTitle("GrocerieList");

            // tree view
            TreeItem<String> root, food, drink;

            root = new TreeItem<>();
            root.setExpanded(true);

            // food
            food = makeBranch("Food",root);
            makeBranch("Banana", food);
            makeBranch("Coconut", food);
            makeBranch("Eggs", food);

            // drink
            drink = makeBranch("Drinks",root);
            makeBranch("Water", drink);
            makeBranch("Fanta", drink);
            makeBranch("Beer", drink);

            // tree
            tree = new TreeView<>(root);
            tree.setShowRoot(false);

            // bottom input fields
            nameInput = new TextField();
            nameInput.setPromptText("Productname");
            nameInput.setMinWidth(100);

            quantityInput = new TextField();
            quantityInput.setPromptText("Quantity");
            quantityInput.setMinWidth(100);

            // buttons
            Button addbutton = new Button("Add");

            // Layout
            // HBOX
            HBox hBox = new HBox();
            hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            hBox.setSpacing(10);
            hBox.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, quantityInput, addbutton);

            // BorderPane
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            borderPane.getChildren().addAll(tree, hBox);
            borderPane.setCenter(tree);
            borderPane.setBottom(hBox);

            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 520, 620);
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();

        }
        public TreeItem<String> makeBranch(String title, TreeItem<String> parent){
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>(title);
            item.setExpanded(true);
            parent.getChildren().add(item);
            return item;
        }
```

Complete error:

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = BorderPane@71e344e8
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:560)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane$BorderPositionProperty.invalidated(BorderPane.java:692)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane.setCenter(BorderPane.java:268)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:70)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```java
BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
borderPane.getChildren().addAll(tree, hBox);
borderPane.setCenter(tree);
borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
```

The calls to `setCenter` and `setBottom` add those nodes to the children list. Since you've manually added the two nodes to the children list, those method calls lead to adding the same node to the same parent twice—that's not allowed. When it comes to layouts that provide special properties for positioning, such as `BorderPane`, you want to avoid interacting with the children list directly. Change your code to:

```java
BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
borderPane.setCenter(tree);
borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
```

Comment: Sweet baby jesus i did not know that! My problem is solved - i wish you the very best Slaw! :)